# Can I access my Ubuntu partition from OSX?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have a MacBook, on which I have a dual-boot setup with OSX and Ubuntu.

When logged in to Ubuntu, I can easily access my files on my OSX drive (albeit read-only).

Is there a way to similarly view my Ubuntu files from OSX?

Comment: What filesystem is being used in your Ubuntu installation? `ext3`? `ext4?` `reiserfs`? `reiser4`?

Comment: It is ext4, according to Ubuntu's Disk Utility. Although OSX's Disk Utility seems to think that it is FAT32, but I think this is a mistake.

Comment: The partitions on a disk may appear in a different order depending upon how the tool displays them. (They can be ordered by physical location on the disk, or the order in which they appear in the partition table. They aren't always the same). If you're sure they're the same partition, then that's particularly weird.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog article](http://blog.applegrew.com/2011/12/access-ext3ext2-file-system-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7/) explains how to setup your Mac in order to get read-only access to Ext2 and Ext3. This solution works with Ext4 too, as noted in the article comments.

You will need to install [OSXFuse](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/downloads) and [Fuse-ext2](http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/fuse-ext2/fuse-ext2-0.0.7.dmg?download).

> Fuse-ext2 needs MacFuse to run, but this is no longer maintained and
>   does not work on Lion. OSXFuse is the next generation MacFuse, but
>   Fuse-ext2 is not meant to work with this. Fortunately OSXFuse includes
>   “MacFUSE Compatibility Layer”. Just make sure to select this option
>   when installing OSXFuse and you are good to go.